# How to keep raspberry ketone from forming crystals again after dissolving in alcohol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, solutions

I dissolved raspberry ketone 700 mg in 10 ml of 99% isopropyl alcohol. The solubility according to pub chem is 1 g/ml. After dissolving, I added room temperature water to bring the final volume to 70 ml but suddenly crystals form again. Why is that? What am I doing wrong? I have to heat it above 90 °C to dissolve it but I'm afraid the melting point is 83 °C.

P.S : I'm not consuming this solution, I'm using it for other applications.

Comment: Just why wouldn't that be?

Comment: Why would the Crystals form again if it's already dissolved ?

Comment: So what? It is quite plausible that your compound is well-soluble in alcohol, but only poorly soluble in water-alcohol mixture.

Answer (score 1):

The solubility data are for the isopropanol, not for the total amount of the solvent in abundance of water.

Check the solubility in water.

Edit: 
The important thing is the compound solubility in the final solvent mixture, not in the initial solvent.

A very rough (as it is generally non-linear) solubility estimation could be done from the molar composition of solvent. The ketone solubility in the used mixture is much closer to its solubility in pure water than to its solubility in pure isopropanol.

If you e.g. make a cupric sulfate water solution and if you add ethanol, the sulfate immediately precipitates as well.

Suggestion:

- make a test for various ratios isopropanol: water,
- note the edge ratio where the ketone seems to stay dissolved yet.
- user as final solvent a mixture with some excess of isopropanol to be on the safe side.
- If it solves perfectly in e.g. 30:70 mixture, use rather 40:60 one.